# How to export data with lazy loading page table in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, export, primefaces, lazy-loading

I have `<p:dataTable lazy="true" ... />` and I want to be able to export the current page with `<p:dataExporter .. />`. If my my total rows count is 12 and my page size is 10, I have two pages. The first page has 10 rows, the second page - 1 row. When I click export and I am on the first page I get 11 rows exported in excel (the first row is duplicated on first and last position). Also if I go to the second page, where I have only 1 row and click export the excel contains 1 row on first position, 9 empty lines and the same row on position 11. Which is very odd.

Answer (score 1):

You need version 3.0.M4 to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What Primefaces Version do you use?

It works fine on lab-showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/exporter.jsf

Have you tried exporting all data(instead of page data) to see what happens? Also try the page export in CSV or even PDF.

Comment: I export all data not page data. I use primefaces 2.2.1. Also this version does not export page footer, but i can't update to newer version right now. And for the lab-showcase table is not lazy loaded.

Comment: Though, if you consider to upgrade, this the migration guide: http://wiki.primefaces.org/display/General/Migration+Guide+to+3.0